# Why is this choice of $y$ not permitted in using pumping lemma?

Tags: pumping-lemma

Consider this snippet shown below from, [An Introduction to Formal Languages and Automata 6th Edition
by Peter Linz](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1284077241).

[image]

As per the text, choosing a value of $y = a^k$, where $k$ is odd is not permitted since this violates the condition of [pumping lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages). This text simply says that the assumption on $k$ (number of $a$'s in $y$ being odd) is not permitted.

Now, as far as my understanding goes, the condition on choosing $xy$ is $|xy| \le p$, where $p$ is the pumping length, and $|y|>1$. And if we can show that one valid choice of $y$ satisfies the pumping lemma, we have been able to show that this language *does  not* violate the pumping lemma, though the language can *not* be claimed to be regular. When I need to show that the language is *not* regular, I need to explore all possible $y$'s.

I fail to understand, why a $y$, with odd number of $a$'s, and $|y| \le p$, $x=\epsilon$, will not be permitted here.

Comment: If you are using the pumping lemma to prove $L$ is not regular then you are not permitted to make the assumption that $y$ has odd length, or any other assumption of this kind. It is not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Would you mind elaborating, "any other assumption of this kind", part?

Comment: I mean anything that is not in the conclusion of the pumping lemma.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Do you want to put a reference in support of your claim? As far as my understanding goes, if I take $y$ to be of odd length, it does not violate the acceptable conditions for $y$.

Comment: What do you mean by "you take y"? You get y from the pumping lemma, and not choose it yourself. I am referring to how you use the pumping lemma to prove a language is not regular. Are you trying to do something else?

Comment: Of course it may just happen that y is of odd length, the pumping lemma doesn't forbid that, if that's what you mean.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Yes, exactly that is what I mean, being $y$ of odd length. What is wrong in using it in completing the proof?

Comment: Then it is not a complete proof because you haven't considered the other case when y is of even length.